# Pattern match a list of any size in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir. I want to define a function that accepts only lists, but that can be of any size.

I could define a function that accepts an empty list like this:

```
def doit(my_list = []) do
  IO.puts my_list
end
```

or just one item, like this:

```
def doit([first]) do
  IO.puts my_list
end
```

but how do I allow any size list? I know I can accept *anything* like this:

```
def doit(my_list) do
  IO.puts my_list
end
```

but wouldn't it be more correct to enforce that it is a list using pattern matching?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As far as I know there's no single pattern to match any list. `[]` will match an empty list and `[_ | _]` will match any non-empty list, but there's no way to combine them using a pattern.

You can do this with function guards though, using `is_list/1`:

```
def doit(my_list) when is_list(my_list) do
  # my_list is guaranteed to be a list
end
```

Comment: Just figured that out myself, but was wondering if there was still a way to use pattern matching. Will accept in a few minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can do it as below with pure pattern match and without the guards:

```
def any_list(list = [head | tail = []]) do
   IO.puts("Single Element")
end
```

```
def any_list(list = [head | tail ]) do
   IO.puts("Any list")
end
```

```
def any_list([]) do
   IO.puts("Empty list")
end
```

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to pattern matching, you can use the [is_list/1 guard function](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/guards.html), which does a type check on the function argument:

```
def doit(my_list) when is_list(my_list) do
  # code goes here
end
```

Or even use it with the size check, if necessary:

```
def doit(my_list) when is_list(my_list) and my_list != [] do
  # code goes here
end
```